How to add a web page and DynamoDB to Alexa skill
How to add a web page with DynamoDB  CRUD to alexa skill in python?
Alexa skills kit is compatible with a java web page and mysql?, I want to create the page with CRUD in Java using MySQL for ease (I'm more proficient in Java than in Python).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
